# Partial View not displaying

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I don't know what is the reason but my partial view is not displaying, I have tried with other view but problem remains same. I am calling this Partial View using @Ajax.ActionLink, I have put debug points, so it clearly shows that it goes to controller method and successfully return Partial View but it is not displaying.

View(Here I am calling Controller Method):

```
<li class="nav-menu">@Ajax.ActionLink("Request for Change MobileNumber and EmailId", "ChangeMob", "Admin", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" })</li>
```

Controller Method:

```
 public ActionResult ChangeMob()
    {
        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            var model = new ChangeMob();
            var db = new clubDataContext();
            var list2 = (from s in db.tblChanges

                         select new ChangeMob()
                         {
                             id= s.Id,
                             oldno = s.Old_CNo,
                             newemail = s.New_Email,
                             oldemail = s.Old_Email,
                             mobileoremail = s.Mob_or_Email,
                             newno = s.New_CNo
                         }).ToList();
            ViewBag.Request = list2;
            return PartialView("ChangeMob", model);
        }
        else
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "home");
    }
```

Partial View:

```
@model IEnumerable<club.Models.ChangeMob>
<h2>Hello there!</h2>

<p>
 @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.oldno)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.newno)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.oldemail)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.newemail)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.mobileoremail)
    </th>
    <th></th>
 </tr>

  @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Request)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @item.oldno
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.newno
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.oldemail
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.newemail
    </td>
    <td>
        @item.mobileoremail
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: what you see n firebug????

Comment: please post the main view as well

Comment: What is firebug? I am not using it, please give brief about it

Comment: i have already posted main view from where i am calling controller method

Comment: @DotNetWeblineindia Please give question link

Comment: is element with id result is present in main view;/

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Yes, obviously it is present

Comment: have you checked firebug console????

Comment: @EhsanSajjad What is firebug? I am not using it, please give brief about it

Comment: In Chrome's Console I got : GET http://localhost:60000/Admin/ChangeMob?X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @SaurabhGadariya : make a new class for ChangeMobList List, set value to that List and pass it to partial view.

Comment: you are getting exception in the action this error simply says error is on server side

Answer (score 2):

I see one mistake in your code.

In ChangeMob Action you returns model of ChangeMob type but partial view has another type:

```
@model IEnumerable<club.Models.ChangeMob>
```

you should change it to

```
@model club.Models.ChangeMob
```

As for partial view displaying. Did you include *"jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"* library for using Ajax.ActionLink?

like this:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your controler return type  from  public **ActionResult** ChangeMob() to public **PartialViewResult** ChangeMob()  and check

And make sure that targetID "result" is not set to dispaly:none

Mark it as answered if it work .